# how do I make a 5 minute loop timer that always "stays on top" when opened with other applications?

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to make a timer thats really similiar to this one: https://www.online-stopwatch.com/loop-countdown/
but I also need it to automatically start at a time that ends with 5 or 0, for example 10:30 or 9:45 + it needs to always "stay on top" so when i click off the window if theres another app open the timer is still on top. I should also mention that I have very little experience with programming so sorry if anything i asked is really obvious/easy, thanks in advance! (btw i use pycharm but im open to trying other applications)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using tkinter put this line of code in at the initialization of you window, replacing `root` with whatever your window name is:

```py
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
```